# Cannot get value of item when set Default value in PropertyMetadata is Array of string

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a `DependencyProperty` in my custom control. I have set the default value of `DayOfWeeksProperty` as an array of values ​​which are strings and then I set `PropertyChangedCallback` as a method where `TextBlock` are set value for each element inside default array.

```
public string[] DayOfWeeks
        {
            get { return (string[])GetValue(DayOfWeeksProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DayOfWeeksProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DayOfWeeks.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DayOfWeeksProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "DayOfWeeks",
                typeof(string[]),
                typeof(ScheduleControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(
                    new string[7] { "Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda" },
                    OnDayOfWeeksChanged)
                );

        private static void OnDayOfWeeksChanged(
            DependencyObject dependencyObject,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ScheduleControl scheduleControl = dependencyObject as ScheduleControl;
            scheduleControl.OnDayOfWeeksChanged(e);
        }

        private void OnDayOfWeeksChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] dayOfWeeks = (string[]) e.NewValue;
            TextBlock_Monday.Text = dayOfWeeks[0];
            TextBlock_Tuesday.Text = dayOfWeeks[1];
            TextBlock_Wednesday.Text = dayOfWeeks[2];
            TextBlock_ThursDay.Text = dayOfWeeks[3];
            TextBlock_Friday.Text = dayOfWeeks[4];
            TextBlock_Saturday.Text = dayOfWeeks[5];
            TextBlock_Sunday.Text = dayOfWeeks[6];
        }
```

XAML

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="cs4rsa_core.Controls.ScheduleControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="TextBlock_TimeLineHeading"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="TextBlock_Monday"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="TextBlock_Tuesday"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2" />
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="TextBlock_Wednesday"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="3" />
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="TextBlock_ThursDay"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="4" />
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="TextBlock_Friday"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="5" />
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="TextBlock_Saturday"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="6" />
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="TextBlock_Sunday"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="7" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="" />
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I want the values ​​in the default array to show up on each `TextBlock` respectively, but when I run the program, nothing happens.

Comment: The DayOfWeeks property is never set to a value other than the default value. The PropertyChangedCallback is hence not called. Be aware that setting a dependency property's default value like this is dangerous. All instances of the control will use the same array. Changes made by one affect all others. Besides that, the whole property declaration is dangerous. What if a user of your control assigns a new string array with less than 7 elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set the default value for it in Constructor, and it worked.

```
public ScheduleControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string[] defaultDayOfWeeks =
    {
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday",
        "Sunday",
    };
    SetValue(DayOfWeeksProperty, defaultDayOfWeeks);
}
```

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/collection-type-dependency-properties?view=netdesktop-6.0

Comment: You would generally use SetCurrentValue instead of SetValue in order to keep the ability to set the property value by a Style.